# IllegalMonitorStateException when using PowerMock to avoid wait() method

Tags: java, tdd, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to avoid the `wait()` method invocation using PowerMock. I've tried with the code below but no success (am I close?). Can anyone help?

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Bar.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException{
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Foo fooSpy = PowerMockito.spy(foo);

        Bar barMock = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);
        PowerMockito.doReturn(barMock).when(fooSpy).getBar();
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(barMock).wait();

        fooSpy.makeBarWait();
    }
}

public class Bar{}

public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void makeBarWait() throws InterruptedException {
        // do something...
        synchronized (this) {               
            getBar().wait();
        }
    }
}
```

I guess the method still being called because I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
```

Comment: @Duncan I've edited the code above

Comment: Since I currently can't reproduce your issue, I've voted to close the question with the "cannot be reproduced" reason.

Answer (score 1):

[Your code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27491766/2) throws a NullPointerException for me. You need to call `makeBarWait()` on the object you have spied upon:

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
  Foo foo = new Foo();
  Foo fooSpy = PowerMockito.spy(foo);

  Bar barMock = PowerMockito.mock(Bar.class);
  PowerMockito.doReturn(barMock).when(fooSpy).getBar();
  PowerMockito.doNothing().when(barMock).wait();

  fooSpy.makeBarWait();  // <-----
}
```

The test then passes for me.

Comment: @Lucas Which version of PowerMock, Mockito and JUnit?

Comment: `<powermock.version>1.6.0</powermock.version>` and `<junit.version>4.11</junit.version>`

Comment: @Lucas Same here. I'm afraid I can't reproduce your problem. Are you testing *exactly* the same code as what you've posted here? I've just used a completely empty class for `Bar`.

Comment: Here is the project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9eKIbGDKXi6U09OcGJLd0M1N0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Lucas Sorry, I don't really want to download files from Google Drive. You need to provide example code in your question that reproduces the issues for others.

Comment: That's ok, the project has the exact same code above and it's throwing IllegalMonitorStateException, can't figured it out how you can run it.

Comment: Different OS? Different compiler? Different JRE version?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl windows, jdk 7